# How does the differential of a complex endomorphism of $\mathbb C^n$ act on $\frac{d}{dz^i}$ and $\frac{d}{d\bar{z}^i}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, complex-geometry, tangent-spaces

I caught myself up in a seemingly simple question. Suppose $f: \mathbb C^n \rightarrow \mathbb C^n$ is a $\mathbb C$-linear map given by a matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb C)$. I am trying to figure out how the differential of $A$ acts on the standard basis in the complexified tangent space $(T {\mathbb{C}}^n)_{\mathbb{C}}$ - this basis denoted $\{ \frac{d}{dz^i}, \frac{d}{d\bar{z}^i} \}_{i=\overline{1,n}}$, where $\frac{d}{dz^i} = \frac{d}{dx^i} + i \frac{d}{dy^i}$ if $(x_i, y_i)$ are the standard real coordinates in $\mathbb C^n$ ($z_i = x_i + iy_i$).

I reasoned as follows. First, we need to see $f$ as a function between differentiable manifolds, $\tilde f:\mathbb R^{2n} \rightarrow \mathbb R^{2n}$. Then $\tilde f$ has matrix $\tilde A \in M_{2n}(\mathbb R)$, where $\tilde A$ is obtained from $A$ by replacing each $A_{ij} \in \mathbb C$ with a $2 \times 2$ real matrix which represents the complex number $A_{ij}$. Then we know that the differential of $\tilde f$ is also given by $\tilde A: T \mathbb R^{2n} \rightarrow T \mathbb R^{2n}$.

Further, I considered the linear map induced between the complexified tangent spaces, which is also $\tilde A$, but seen as a matrix in $M_{2n}(\mathbb C)$.

Now, I reasoned that to obtain the action of the differential of the initial function $f$ on $\frac{d}{dz^i}$ and $\frac{d}{d\bar z^i}$, we must do a change of basis in the complexified tangent space $(T \mathbb R^{2n})\otimes \mathbb C$, from the $\mathbb C$-basis $\{ \frac{d}{dx^i}, \frac{d}{dy^i} \}$ to the basis $\{ \frac{d}{dz^i}, \frac{d}{d\bar{z}^i} \}$. I calculated the change of basis matrix to be:

$$
U = \begin{pmatrix}
I_n & I_n \\
iI_n & -i I_n
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now I am left with the very ugly matrix:
$$
U^{-1} \tilde{A} U
$$
which I have virtually no idea how to relate to the initial $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with complex entries.

So my question is two-fold:

1. Is there something wrong with my approach? Or maybe I calculated $U$ wrongly?
2. If not, is there any way to express $U^{-1} \tilde{A} U$ in a "nice" way? Or anyway, is there a way to easily see the action of the differential of $f$ on $\frac{d}{dz^i}$ and $\frac{d}{d\bar{z}^i}$?

Comment: Just to note, your formula for $\partial/\partial z^{j}$ is not OK (wrong sign, missing factor of $1/2$; $dz^{j} = dx^{j} + i\, dy^{j}$). <> It's a good idea to carefully write out for yourself what happens in one variable, where the complexified tangent space is real four-dimensional. Whether or not your $U$ is OK depends on the **specific isomorphism** used between $\mathbf{C}^n$ and $\mathbf{R}^{2n}$. The two standard choices are "$n \times n$ matrix of $2\times2$ blocks" (replace $z^j$ by $(x^j,y^j)$) and a $2\times2$ block matrix (collect real and imaginary parts separately).

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang As I mentioned, the isomorphism I use between $\mathbb C^n$ and $\mathbb R^{2n}$ is the first one you mention, replacement of each complex number by $2\times 2$ blocks. I don't see how the choice of this iso comes into play when defining the change of basis matrix, since the $dz^i$ are only defined in terms of the basis $dx^i, dx^j$; perhaps you could clarify that dependence? To my mind, there was no need of an isomorphism for $U$ because what happens on the tangent space only depends on canonical properties of the complexification.

Comment: (i) Loosely, it's the difference between ordering our coordinates $(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, \ldots, x_n, y_n)$ (which you've done) and $(x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ (which gives a $U$ of the type written if I understand the notation). But maybe more to the point, (ii) The action of $A$ on the $(1,0)$ tangent bundle is multiplication by $A$, while the induced action on the $(0, 1)$ tangent bundle is ... something closely related but not $A$. _That_ block matrix is presumably the understanding you're aiming for?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang (ii) Yes, I want to know the action of $A$ on the $(0,1)$ tangent bundle, that's precisely it! I assumed it would be something like the action of the conjugation of $A$, right? So then the action of $f_*$ on the complexified tangent bundle is a $2n \times 2n$ matrix made of $4$ $n \times n$ blocks, the upper left one being $A$, the lower right one being $\bar A$ (or whatever it is on $(0,1)$), and the other two being $0 \in M_n(\mathbb C)$, right? But I'd also like to know how I would justify this... (This justification is what I attempted with the reasoning I presented.)

Comment: (As a slight aside, at this point it's not even clear to me how I would justify that $f_*$ invariates $T^{1,0}$ and $T^{0,1}$...)

Comment: It should help to write $A = B + iC$ with $B$ and $C$ real, and think about (i) how $B$ and $C$ act on the complexified space $V\otimes\mathbf{C}$, and (ii) the fact that the $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ spaces are eigenspaces of the complex structure $J$ of $V$ viewed as acting on the complexification.